# "Int" object not iterable for a leap year program

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, iterable

I am making a program to calculate if the given input is a leap year or not. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10 with Anaconda Shell.
It's a silly program and I dont understand why I am getting this error. There are a couple of solutions to this particular program online but I want to make my version work. Please help!

I am getting the error message "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
I tried googling stuff and looking through some previous answers here but I am confused!

```
def sort_year(user_input):
    for i,j in range(0,9):
        if user_input == [ij00]:
            leap_yr1(user_input)
        else:
            leap_yr2(user_input)

def leap_yr1(user_input):
    if user_input % 400 == 0:
        print("The given year is a leap year")
    else:
        print("The given year is not a leap year")

def leap_yr2(user_input):
    if user_input % 4 == 0:
        print("The given year is a leap year")
    else:
        print("The given year is not a leap year")

print("Which year do you want to check?: ")
user_input = int(raw_input())
sort_year(user_input)
```

Comment: You are trying to unpack each value of `range(0, 9)` as 2-tuple. And what do you expect `ij00` to do?

Comment: To be fair, `int` objects aren't iterable for *any* program, leap year or otherwise.

Comment: You *could* write:  `if year % 4 != 0: return false: elif year % 100  != 0: return true: else return year % 400 == 0` rather than have two functions. - That's not your problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you try to write

```
for i in range(0,9):
   for j in range(0,9):
```

But I think you try to check two last digits in `user_input` so you don't need `for`.

If `number` has `00` at the end then `number % 100 == 0` (here `%`  means function `modulo`)

```
def sort_year(user_input):
    if user_input % 100 == 0:
        leap_yr1(user_input)
    else:
        leap_yr2(user_input)
```

Comment: Thanks furas, that helped. I was making a very silly mistake.